# Android Remote database Access

Tags: android

I want to read values from remote database in android.I have two class's `mainActivity.java` and `list.java` .In `mainActivity.java` class hava a Button `Read`. After Clicking this button I want to show database values in `list.java` class. with the help of intent I can move to second activity but how to show values in second Activity or where should write "Database Access Code" in `mainActivit.java` class or `list.java` class.

Comment: Where is your database, In Sqlite or others?

Comment: host on 000webhost.com ,It's working correct but problem is how to show values by clicking on "Read" Button on second activity

Comment: What you try any code?

Answer (score 0):

In the mainActivity , in the click listener of the button, fire of  the list activity and in the oncreate create an asynctask that will fetch the values from the db and then in the postExecute , set the values to the adapter associated with the listview of the list.java activity